# Iterate through two columns and match values from different rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas DataFrame looks like this:

```
            ID                      NAME  PARENT_ID
0            1                    Fruits          0
1            2                   Bananas          1
2            3                    Apples          1
3            4                   Peaches          1
4            5                     Pears          1
```

I would like to iterate through rows and map `PARENT_ID` to actual `NAME` values, creating a new column called `PARENT_NAME`, like this:

```
            ID                      NAME  PARENT_ID   PARENT
0            1                    Fruits          0      NaN
1            2                   Bananas          1   Fruits
2            3                    Apples          1   Fruits
3            4                   Peaches          1   Fruits
4            5                     Pears          1   Fruits
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `df['PARENT'] = df['PARENT_ID'].map(df.set_index('ID')['NAME'])`

Comment: @user3483203 Thank you so much! Was racking my brain over this for a day

Comment: @user3483203: nice short way. Why don't you create an answer for that?

Comment: This needs to be closed as a dupe of a question on [pandas] map column ; ythere are [1216 such questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+map+column+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @user3483203 's answer:

```
df['PARENT'] = df['PARENT_ID'].map(df.set_index('ID')['NAME'])
```